# React Material UI - Autocomplete Component button after clear field button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a search button my `Autocomplete` Component on Material UI. So far I have been able to add the button however, it always appears before the clear button like below:

[image]

How can I set the `InputProps` such that the button will appear after the `X`.

So far I have:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="search-input"
    freeSolo                                   
    renderInput={(params) => (                    
        <TextField
            {...params} 
            placeholder={`...`} 
            margin="normal" 
            variant="outlined" 
            size="medium"
            InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                endAdornment: (
                <React.Fragment>                          
                    <IconButton size="small">
                        <SearchIcon />
                    </IconButton>    
                    {params.InputProps.endAdornment}               
                </React.Fragment>
                ),
            }}
        />  
    )}
/>
```

I have tried replacing the order of `...params.InputProps` and the `endAdornment` but nothing changes.

Comment: Ah... I see the Clear button is using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you inspect the elements within the `Autocomplete` in the dev tools, you'll see the following: an `input` representing the search area, the end adornment of the `TextField` which in your case is a `button` with a `SearchIcon` and a div with the class `MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment` which holds the clear icon. These appear on the screen in that order from left to right. These are all siblings within a `div` that has the CSS property: `display: inline-flex`. This means the siblings can be re-ordered using [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order). We want to show the elements in the following order from left to right: input, clear icon and search icon.

**How**

We can achieve this by overriding existing styles. Since the `div` which houses these three elements is a child of the root of the `TextField` component, we can apply the styling to the root class of the `TextField`.

1. Create class called textFieldRoot - you can call it whatever you want.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textFieldRoot: {
    "& > div.MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot[class*='MuiOutlinedInput-root']": {
      // default paddingRight was 39px since clear icon was positioned absolute
      paddingRight: "9px", 
      
      // Search icon
      "& button": {
        order: 3, // order 3 means the search icon will appear after the clear icon which has an order of 2
      },

      // Clear icon
      "& > div.MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment": {
        position: "relative", // default was absolute. we make it relative so that it is now within the flow of the other two elements
        order: 2,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

2. Apply the class to the root of the `TextField`

```
const classes = useStyles();

<Autocomplete
  id="search-input"
  freeSolo
  options={[]}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      classes={{
        root: classes.textFieldRoot, // apply class here
      }}
      placeholder={`...`}
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      size="medium"
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        endAdornment: (
          <React.Fragment>
            <IconButton size="small">
              <SearchIcon />
            </IconButton>
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
          </React.Fragment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

**Result**
[image: Autocomplete with Search Icon at end after clear icon]

**Alternative**

As you can see, it is a bit of work. I would consider using `startAdornment` instead of `endAdornment` in your `InputProps` to place the search icon at the front of the search bar.